# Incrementing through POST variables

Tags: php, arrays, forms, post

I am making a website that has `x` amount of input fields. Each of the input fields is labeled `team0`, `team1`, `team2` ... `teamx` and they are wrapped in a post form. Upon posting, I would like to check the POST variables, store them in an array, print out their values, but it seems I cannot use a variable when calling `$_POST`. I have tried it like so:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $NUMBER_OF_TEAMS; $i++) {
    $teamNames[$i] = $_POST['team$i'];
    echo $teamNames[$i] . "<br>";
}
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Variable interpolation only works within double quotes. And input fields could be arrays already by using `<input name="team[1]">` etc.

Comment: @mario Thanks! I'll try to rework my input fields to make them into an array.

Comment: Why not just use a `foreach` to loop through the `$_POST` array?

Comment: @mario Changing the input fields into arrays per your suggestion `<input name="team[1]">` etc creates an `undefined index` error when I try to reference them later using `$_POST[team[1]]`. Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: Like normal arrays, `$_POST["team"][1]`.

Comment: @mario Gotcha! Thanks for the help. Still new to PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try double quotes

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $NUMBER_OF_TEAMS; $i++) {
    $teamNames[$i] = $_POST["team$i"];
    echo $teamNames[$i] . "<br>";
}
```

OR

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $NUMBER_OF_TEAMS; $i++) {
    $teamNames[$i] = $_POST['team'.$i];
    echo $teamNames[$i] . "<br>";
}
```